# How to stream only audio/video from mpeg file using gstreamer?

Tags: gstreamer, rtp, mpeg

I am new for gstreamer. I want to stream only audio/video on a rtp port. I tried following command to stream only video from mpeg file :

```
    $ gst-launch-1.0 -v rtpbin name=rtpbin filesrc location=KRSNA.mpg ! decodebin ! 'video/mpeg' ! rtpmpvpay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=9078
```

Following is the verbose for command :

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING  ...
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstTypeFindElement:typefind.GstPad:src: caps = video/mpeg, systemstream=(boolean)true, mpegversion=(int)1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstTypeFindElement:typefind.GstPad:src: caps = video/mpeg, systemstream=(boolean)true, mpegversion=(int)1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstMpegPSDemux:mpegpsdemux0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/mpeg, systemstream=(boolean)true, mpegversion=(int)1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstMultiQueue:multiqueue0.GstPad:sink_0: caps = video/mpeg, mpegversion=(int)1, systemstream=(boolean)false
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstMultiQueue:multiqueue0.GstPad:sink_0: caps = video/mpeg, mpegversion=(int)1, systemstream=(boolean)false
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstMpegvParse:mpegvparse0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/mpeg, mpegversion=(int)1, systemstream=(boolean)false
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstMultiQueue:multiqueue0.GstPad:sink_1: caps = audio/mpeg, mpegversion=(int)1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstMultiQueue:multiqueue0.GstPad:sink_1: caps = audio/mpeg, mpegversion=(int)1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstMultiQueue:multiqueue0.GstPad:sink_1: caps = audio/mpeg, mpegversion=(int)1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstMpegAudioParse:mpegaudioparse0.GstPad:src: caps = audio/mpeg, mpegversion=(int)1, mpegaudioversion=(int)1, layer=(int)2, rate=(int)48000, channels=(int)2, parsed=(boolean)true
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstMpg123AudioDec:mpg123audiodec0.GstPad:sink: caps = audio/mpeg, mpegversion=(int)1, mpegaudioversion=(int)1, layer=(int)2, rate=(int)48000, channels=(int)2, parsed=(boolean)true
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstMpegvParse:mpegvparse0.GstPad:src: caps = video/mpeg, mpegversion=(int)1, systemstream=(boolean)false, parsed=(boolean)true, width=(int)720, height=(int)576, framerate=(fraction)25/1, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)16/15, codec_data=(buffer)000001b32d0240830c352398
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/avdec_mpeg2video:avdec_mpeg2video0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/mpeg, mpegversion=(int)1, systemstream=(boolean)false, parsed=(boolean)true, width=(int)720, height=(int)576, framerate=(fraction)25/1, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)16/15, codec_data=(buffer)000001b32d0240830c352398
Redistribute latency...
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstMpg123AudioDec:mpg123audiodec0.GstPad:src: caps = audio/x-raw, format=(string)S16LE, layout=(string)interleaved, rate=(int)48000, channels=(int)2, channel-mask=(bitmask)0x0000000000000003
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/avdec_mpeg2video:avdec_mpeg2video0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)I420, width=(int)720, height=(int)576, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)16/15, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, colorimetry=(string)bt601, framerate=(fraction)25/1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstMultiQueue:multiqueue0: max-size-buffers = 5
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstMultiQueue:multiqueue0: max-size-time = 0
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstMultiQueue:multiqueue0: max-size-bytes = 2097152
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstMultiQueue:multiqueue0: max-size-buffers = 5
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstMultiQueue:multiqueue0: max-size-time = 0
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstMultiQueue:multiqueue0: max-size-bytes = 2097152
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstCapsFilter:capsfilter1: caps = video/mpeg
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstCapsFilter:capsfilter2: caps = video/mpeg
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstMpg123AudioDec:mpg123audiodec0.GstPad:src: caps = audio/x-raw, format=(string)S16LE, layout=(string)interleaved, rate=(int)48000, channels=(int)2, channel-mask=(bitmask)0x0000000000000003
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0.GstDecodePad:src_1: caps = audio/x-raw, format=(string)S16LE, layout=(string)interleaved, rate=(int)48000, channels=(int)2, channel-mask=(bitmask)0x0000000000000003
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0.GstDecodePad:src_1.GstProxyPad:proxypad8: caps = audio/x-raw, format=(string)S16LE, layout=(string)interleaved, rate=(int)48000, channels=(int)2, channel-mask=(bitmask)0x0000000000000003
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/avdec_mpeg2video:avdec_mpeg2video0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)I420, width=(int)720, height=(int)576, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)16/15, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, colorimetry=(string)bt601, framerate=(fraction)25/1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0.GstDecodePad:src_0: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)I420, width=(int)720, height=(int)576, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)16/15, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, colorimetry=(string)bt601, framerate=(fraction)25/1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0.GstDecodePad:src_0.GstProxyPad:proxypad9: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)I420, width=(int)720, height=(int)576, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)16/15, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, colorimetry=(string)bt601, framerate=(fraction)25/1
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstMpegPSDemux:mpegpsdemux0: Internal data stream error.
Additional debug info:
gstmpegdemux.c(2871): gst_flups_demux_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstMpegPSDemux:mpegpsdemux0:
stream stopped, reason not-linked
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

How to stream only audio/video from mpeg file using gstreamer ?

Any help/pointers appriciated ...

Answer (score 0):

Please try not using `decodebin`. Use the compatible demuxer element and then use the required parser and decoder elements.

If you want to run elementary (only video / only audio) out of a container format, use the required elements ( video elements for video stream / audio elements for audio stream).

```
gst-launch-0.10  filesrc  location=sample.mkv ! matroskademux ! h264parse ! ffdec_h264 ! ffmpegcolorspace ! autovideosink
```

The above statement for example will give the video output ignoring audio and same can be achieved for audio.

Hope this helps, also look [here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gst-launch-0.10)

Answer (score 0):

```
gst-launch-0.10 filesrc location=c:/test.mpg ! mpegpsdemux ! mpegvideoparse ! mpeg2dec ! rtpvrawpay ! udpsink port=9078
```

This pipeline works for me, although I had to substitute mpegpsdemux for tsdemux, since I only had the former installed.